# Google Sheets Conditional Formatting based on the cell directly NEXT to, across the entire row

Tags: google-sheets, cell

I am looking to show color changes based on decreasing values. I want to add conditional formatting to a row (row 9) based on the cell directly prior (B9<C9 I want to be green, C9>D9 I want to be red). I want an entire row to be conditionally formatted to show growth/decline based on the cell directly before. Is this possible? How can I do so? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQq49.png)I have the formulas I want to use, but I don't know how to accurate apply them to the entire Row 9 (as of now I'm manually inputting the 3 custom conditions on each cell)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following Custom Formulas from Range C9:9. Feel free to interchange the background color that will fit your needs.

- For Green (Increasing), `=C9>OFFSET(C9,0,-1)`
- For Red (Decreasing), `=C9<OFFSET(C9,0,-1)`
- For Yellow (Same), `=C9=OFFSET(C9,0,-1)`

[OFFSET()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093379?hl=en) lets you shift the rows/columns based on a reference cell.
In this custom formulas, I get the previous cell value referenced to the current cell by setting the `offset_columns` to `-1`.

### **Sample:**

[image]

### **Output:**

[image]